# jQuery loses added class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have several buttons with a class `mybtn`. I need to set a class `mybtn-active` on the one that is clicked, and remove it from the one that has it at the moment.

```
$('.mybtn').on('click', function () {
    $('.mybtn-active').removeClass('mybtn-active');
    $(this).addClass('mybtn-active');
});
```

When I click on a button, currently active loses its class, as it should. But the clicked one doesn't get the class.

I passed through the script with Chrome debugger and it works. It just loses the class when the code exits the script. Any ideas?

**[SOLUTION]** by @musefan
The buttons were `<a>` tags in the background, which I didn't think about because this is the code I inherited, I didn't write the HTML. And that was the problem. See the accepted answer.

Comment: `$('mybtn-active')` is not going to select any elements with the _class_ `mybtn-active` ...

Comment: `$('mybtn-active')` should be `$('.mybtn-active')`

Comment: _“It just loses the class when the code exits the script. Any ideas?”_ - classes don’t get “lost” on their own ... your code snippet is not enough to reproduce the problem, so please go read [mcve].

Comment: It's working good https://jsfiddle.net/YuriJF/Lg1bbLxn/2/

Comment: @010Pixel: That's a horrible suggestion. Why would you do that? Just adding complication and extra performance overhead just to put it on one line?? If you don't like multiple lines just remove the line break, no need to make the code worse in the process

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Assumptions**

I am going to take a massive gamble here, but it's the only thing I can think of that would explain what the OP is describing and could actually happen with that code. We would need the OP to provide HTML to validate my assumption.

I am also assuming that the class selector in the sample code is a typo of the question, and is not a problem in the original code (as the OP specifically says the removal of the classes is working correctly).

My assumptions have since been validated by the OP in comments on this answer and other answers.

**Problem**

I expect your problem is that you are using either `a` elements and your click is ***actually reloading the page***, or using buttons that are also having the same effect, thus causing all classes to revert to default.

**Solution**

You can fix this by using the arguments of the click event as follows:

```
$('.mybtn').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // This prevent the hyperlink from reloading the page.
    $('.mybtn-active').removeClass('mybtn-active');
    $(this).addClass('mybtn-active');
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The buttons are, in fact, links and you are very correct about this. When I prevent default, the classes remain. Now I just have to re-fire event :) Thank you for considering my question valid, too.

Comment: @dzenesiz: no problem, but please add your HTML to your question so we can identify the problem more accurately.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a

> .

in the selector on your second line.

It should be

```
$('.mybtn-active').removeClass('mybtn-active');
```

Comment: Maybe, but the OP says that part is working... it's the adding of the class to `this` that supposedly doesn't work. So if what the OP says is correct, then it's probably just a typo in the question.

Answer (score 1):

As I have mentioned in the comment, it is typo mistake. You have to change `$('mybtn-active')` to `$('.mybtn-active')`. Look at the snippet.

```js
$('.mybtn').on('click', function () {
    $('.mybtn-active').removeClass('mybtn-active');
    $(this).addClass('mybtn-active');
});
```

```css
.mybtn-active {
 font-size:25px; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="mybtn">Button1</button>
<button class="mybtn">Button2</button>
<button class="mybtn">Button3</button>
<button class="mybtn">Button4</button>
```

Comment: Yeah, but that isn't the problem that the OP is describing. They clearly say that the part of removing the class is working correctly, so surely it's just a typo in the question. The OP says the problem is with applying the class to the clicked element.

Comment: @musefan As per the snippet applying class is working fine.

Comment: Yes, but a question isn't just a snippet of code, it is also the description of the problem. It is obvious that the OP needs to provide more information, but my point is your answer does not solve the problem that is being *described* in the question

Comment: ok..let see what OP is giving answer for this.

Comment: The mistake is in the question, not the code. Class names are in my language, so I thought that it would be easier for people this way